# PHP PEAR: Can Net_SMTP use Auth_SASL2?

Tags: php, pear

Normally `Auth_SASL` is an optional dependency of `Net_SMTP` in the PEAR module. However, since `AUTH_SASL` is deprecated in favor of **`Auth_SASL2`**, does that imply that **`AUTH_SASL2`** is also an optional dependency of `Net_SMTP`?

I took a look at the docs [here](https://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP), but it did not provide the information I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a separate **PEAR** package for **`Net_SMTP2`** as well, located **[here](https://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP2)**. So, in summary:

- `Net_SMTP` has a dependency of `Auth_SASL`
- `New_SMTP2` has a dependency of `Auth_SASL2`